# How to simply compile a big python program with huge number of files, for linux, mac and windows

Tags: python-3.x, compilation, multiplatform, source-code-protection

I have made a program for my company using PyQt5 with many files and dependencies. How can I compile to distribute it ?
My boss want the code to be invisible and the program must be able to run without bugs on Windows, Mac and Linux. I develop the code on a computer running on Linux (Ubuntu).

I saw that there is many possibilities to do this using for instance cython but It seems very complicated to run on a big program with many dependencies. Any help would be very much appreciated as we are totally in a hurry, thanks a lot in advance !

EDIT : Thanks for answering with a duplicate but the problem is I already tried what is mentionned in this subject and it is not working well. Probably because my program is very far form been a single file.

Comment: Can you reopen the subject please ?